# WS-Federation - decrypt Cookie from SecurityContextToken

Tags: c#, encryption, ws-federation

We have implemented WSFederation and we would like to have integration tests, for that we would need to be able to get User Claims from idsrvauth Cookie.

I'm able to get idsrvauth and idsrvauth1 cookie. And then with following code I try to decode cookie

```cs
var auth = WebResp.Cookies["idsrvauth"].Value + WebResp.Cookies["idsrvauth1"].Value;

byte[] authBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(auth);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(authBytes);         


var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var thumbprint = "********";
var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

List<CookieTransform> sessionTransforms = new List<CookieTransform>(new CookieTransform[]
   {
        new DeflateCookieTransform(),
        new RsaSignatureCookieTransform(certs[0]),
        new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(certs[0])
   });

SessionSecurityTokenHandler sessionHandler = new SessionSecurityTokenHandler(sessionTransforms.AsReadOnly());

SecurityTokenResolver resolver;
{
    var token = new X509SecurityToken(certs[0]);    
    var tokens = new List<SecurityToken>() { token };    
    resolver = SecurityTokenResolver.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenResolver(tokens.AsReadOnly(), false);
}

sessionHandler.Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration();
sessionHandler.Configuration.IssuerTokenResolver = resolver;


var xmlSett = new XmlReaderSettings();

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedString)), xmlSett))
{
    var theToken = sessionHandler.ReadToken(reader);
}
```

Decoded and combined cookies (idsrvauth and idsrvauth1) look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SecurityContextToken p1:Id="_564051b3-57ad-41de-831f-41beda49d8e8-7D534CD4043540BBB2EE96A4ADB59C42" xmlns:p1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512">
  <Identifier>urn:uuid:8614f321-2f9d-4332-a1d9-8ea00190bd52
  </Identifier>
  <Cookie xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/security">AAEAAA *** [Totaly 2064 chars]
  </Cookie>
</SecurityContextToken>
```

All I get while trying to get token (sessionHandler.ReadToken(reader)) is error :

**Additional information: ID1006: The format of the data is incorrect. The encryption key length is negative: '-666895530'. The cookie may have been truncated.**

Is the approach correct ? Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: You've probably either solved this or found another way, but just wanted to comment on an observation I made. Dynamics CRM removes the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` before calling ReadToken. It also has the same sessionTransforms as your code. Perhaps that'll do the trick.